# How to use Valence API in my widget?

Tags: jquery, api, desire2learn, valence

I'm trying to create a custom widget in our D2L LMS test environment system that would populate the widget with the instructor user profile image and name in the course Home page. I was told that I could use the Valence API to do that, so I read all the documentation at Valence http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/. Then I registered my widget within the Manage Extensibility admin tool in my LMS (even though I'm not using an external app). I also downloaded the client libraries javascript version from the https://github.com/Brightspace/valence-sdk-javascript/releases, made some changes to add my own API Key and ID and uploaded them into my course Manage Files valenceJS folder.

In my widget I'm trying to test the API call using the whoamI call by adding the code below:

```
<div style="width: 250px; max-width: 250px; overflow: hidden;">
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined'){  
document.write('<script type="text/javascript"         src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"><\/script>');
}
// ]]></script>
<script type="text/javascript"     src="https://learntest.<mysite>/{OrgUnitPath}/valenceJS/valence.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript"     src="https://learntest..<mysite>/{OrgUnitPath}/valenceJS/sha.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript"      src="https://learntest..<mysite>/{OrgUnitPath}/valenceJS/sample1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://learntest..<mysite>/{OrgUnitPath}/valenceJS/server2.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://learntest..<mysite>/{OrgUnitPath}/valenceJS/jquery.jsonp -2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready( function () {
$('#iInfo').load('/d2l/api/lp/1.0/users/whoamI', function(responseTxt,     statusTxt, xhr){
        if(statusTxt == "success")
            $('#error').text("API loaded successfully!");
        if(statusTxt == "error")
            $('#error').text("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " +     xhr.statusText);
    });
    });
// ]]></script>
<div id="iInfo" style="padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;"></div>
<p id="error" style="color: red;"></p>
</div>
```

However, my widget shows Error 403 Forbidden and the system freezes. Then, I took out the scripts that insert the files and it is still showing Error 403 Forbidden, but the system does not freeze any more.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong as I'm not using an external app within the API, I'm inside the LMS as the widget is a LMS tool, so I'm confused why I had to registered the widget and get the API Key and ID and how the authentication works in this case. I tested my API key and ID within the API Test Tool and it worked returning results for this whoamI call '.

I'm logged in to the LMS as an admin with the higher security levels and still get the 403 Forbidden. Same when I logged in with my student account to the LMS.

Thanks for the help and attention.

Answer (score 0):

Please see https://community.brightspace.com/devcop/f_technical/help_with_make_an_api_call_within_my_widget for the answer.

From the link:

> The answer to this question depends on your version of Brightspace.
>
> If your version is 10.4.7 or higher, you shouldn’t need to use Valence authentication because the cookies Brightspace uses should work.
>
> If your version is prior to 10.4.7, you’re going to need to create a web application that can proxy appropriate Valence requests from your Widget to Brightspace. You can add the Valence authentication in there (i.e., a web application that exposes the subset of the Valence APIs that you’re using which forwards the request on to Brightspace after generating an authenticated URL). This is because prior to 10.4.7, Valence APIs use a different method to authenticate incoming requests, even for Widgets.

Comment: This is absolutely the right answer. Please note one thing that Jeff's answer did not explicitly state -- using Valence Auth completely on the client side is a _very bad idea_ because it exposes the Application's ID/Key pair to the user agent and this is a security risk. The Valence IDKey authentication scheme is designed for three-legged authentication, not two-legged: be aware if you're using client-side application code like this, you're behaving insecurely and you should proceed with extreme caution or not proceed at all.